# My Procedure expects a Parameter but I already provided it?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I got the following method in my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to add a new log entry in the database.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logId">The ID of the log</param>
/// <param name="severityLevel">The Severity Level of the Entry</param>
/// <param name="entry">The Entry text</param>
/// <returns>A message depending on success or failure to add the message.</returns>
public static String AddNewLogEntry(int logId, int severityLevel, String entry)
{
    String returnMsg = "";

    using (SqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "AddLogEntry";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logId", logId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@severityLevel", severityLevel);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entry", entry);

            SqlParameter returnParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@returnMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            returnMsg = (String)returnParam.Value;

            if (!returnMsg.Contains("Log ID") || !returnMsg.Contains("Severity Level"))
            {
                String[] parameters = returnMsg.Split('¤');
                returnMsg = parameters[0];
                int entryId = Int32.Parse(parameters[1]);
                Utility.ReportIncident(logId, severityLevel, entry, entryId);
            }
        }
    }

    return returnMsg;
}
```

On this line here:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It fails telling me that the procedure needs a parameter called "@returnMsg" and that I need to pass it to the method. However as you can see here:

```
SqlParameter returnParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@returnMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar);
returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

I already did that. So what would be the issue then?

**EDIT**

Since GarethD didn't get back to me I went with the temporary solution to return a number depending on what happens in the IF/ELSE branches and then act accordingly with that.

Comment: What's the parameter list for `AddLogEntry`? You could be missing a parameter earlier in the call signature and 'returnMsg' is the first one that's missing.

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument be the value?

Comment: I don't think you wanted to use `AddWithValue` and set it's value to `SqlDbType.VarChar`.  You might want to stop using `AddWithValue` anyway, read [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: `ReturnValue` -> `Output`?

Comment: Could you show the declaration of your stored procedure? IE what parameters are expected? I bet you have an OUTPUT parameter not a ReturnValue

Comment: By convention ReturnValue is an integer where anything other than zero means an error occurred. You probably want to use OUTPUT instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you add the parameter you are confusing the arguments for `ParameterCollection.Add()` and `ParameterCollection.AddWithValue()`, so here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@returnMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar)
```

You are not defining a parameter with a type of `SqlDbType.VarChar` you are defining a parameter that has a value of that. Which I think probably does something funny to the internals of `AddWithValue()` and is the source of your error.

You should be able to avoid this by using `Add()` instead of `AddWithValue()` ([which is pretty sound advice whenever you are adding parameters](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/))

```
SqlParameter returnParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

*n.b. I have guessed at the length of your varchar, you may need to adjust it*

Also, return value can only be an integer, so I assume `@returnMsg` is in fact an output parameter, in which case you would use:

```
SqlParameter returnParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOut;
```

Comment: Alright, well thanks for explaining. I will try that as soon as I can :)

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it says the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses `Parameters.AddWithValue()`

This is a return value you're not passing a value. You should just use

```
Parameters.Add()
```

Also make sure you're `SqlDbType` matches the SQL code return type.

Hope this helps!